# Content text with image and vertical sidebar

Tags: html, css

Hello Guys I need help with my work, I have to make a page same as https://ibb.co/Z1tZGs3.
I already created header and footer.
but I couldn't create that main content with navbar in vertical and lorem ipsum with image like in the picture link.
when I put image my footer goes up so I have to fix that also.
How can I do it? someone pls help me to create the middle page like in picture putting navbar, lorem ipsum with that page on right in a small box.

This is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: harmy;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

header {
  background-color: #9cd5e8;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  color: #838478
}

header.cut {
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

h1.light {
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.cut {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.lorem {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #7fbec0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}

.foto {
  width: 250;
  height: 180;
  padding: 50px;
}

.sfondo {
  background-color: #e2e7e2;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />

  <title>ORIZZONTE VIAGGI</title>
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: harmy;
      src: url('./font.woff');
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cut">
    <header>
      <h1 class="light">&nbsp;Orizzonte Viaggi</h1>

    </header>
    <img src="img/beach.jpg" alt="spiaggia" width="1515" height="420" />

  </div>
  <div class="sfondo">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Praesent</li>
        <li>Bibendum</li>
        <li>Donec</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="lorem">

      <h1 class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <div class="left">
        <p>Phasellus iaculis. Proin viverra tempor <br> enim. Cras lectus elit, luctus ut, tristique sed, aliquam at, ligula. Nam adipiscing. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
          mus. In bibendum. Aenean ornare, nunc eget pretium porttitor, sem est pretium leo, non euismod nulla dui non diam. Pellentesque dictum faucibus leo. Vestibulum ac ante. Sed in est.
        </p>
      </div>
      <img class="foto" src="img/thumb-img1.jpg" alt="foto" align="right" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cut">
    <div class="footer">

      <p>
        © 2020 <u>Harman</u>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you want the footer to always stay at the bottom then you have to add `bottom: 0;`. In this case it would work because you also used `position: fixed;` in the footer.

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 Thanks, And do you know how can i create main of the page? same as picture https://ibb.co/Z1tZGs3 , that lorem ipsum part with image?

Comment: You could use floats. Here's a link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float2

Comment: It will also work with ul? @GucciBananaKing99

Comment: https://ibb.co/b3NRsj2 it must be like this but i can't put that ipsum text with image on another type of background @GucciBananaKing99

Comment: use ids for your left and right divs and then position them inline-block to see them side by side. Also you should use the native footer tag instead of using a footer div. You can center align text by using text-align. https://jsfiddle.net/3wjfakq4/

Comment: thnx very much @RachelGallen